# CSS alternating table row to reset in a new table?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I have 2 tables and would like alternating row colors to reset based on a new table. the `tr:odd` seems to be applied across both of my tables.

Here's my table html:

```
<table class='myTable'>
    <tr class='myRow'>
        <td>row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='myRow'>
        <td>row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='myRow'>
        <td>row 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<hr>
<table class='myTable'>
    <tr class='myRow'>
        <td>row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='myRow'>
        <td>row 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
.myAltRowClass { background: #DDDDDC; }
```

javascript:

```
$(".myTable .myRow:odd").addClass('myAltRowClass');
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/niner/Sgq9T/

The 1st table and 2nd table both have alternating colors, but the 1st row in table 2 should start out with the normal (white) color, and not the alternate (grey) color.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, just select the rows of each `table` independantly:

```
$(".myTable").find('.myRow:odd').addClass('myAltRowClass');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Sgq9T/1/).

Or, preferably, just use CSS:

```
table.myTable tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #DDDDDC;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Sgq9T/4/).

Note that I've switched to `even` in the CSS `:nth-child()` example, this is because JavaScript is zero-based, whereas CSS is one-based.

Or by combining the two approaches together:

```
$('.myTable tr:nth-child(even)').addClass('myAltRowClass');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Sgq9T/7/).

Comment: @Niner: you're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have been of help! =)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS3 selector `:nth-child(odd)` (or `even` if that's what you need) which will work in jQuery too. Better than `:odd` anyways, because that is not a natively supported selector and jQuery cannot use the more performant native `querySelectorAll` for it (as described [in the docs](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/)).

```
$(".myTable .myRow:nth-child(odd)")
    .addClass('myAltRowClass');
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sgq9T/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to these: jQuery's :odd, :even, etc pseudo-class selectors DON'T behave the way you think they do; they look for e.g. the odd members of the jQuery array created by the preceding selector. You could think of $('.myTable .myRow:odd') as creating an intermediary array of objects based on $('.myTable .myRow') and then removing the even numbered elements from that array. Similar for :even, :first, and so on (although nth-child() is different and does do what you might expect).